# ehcache - faulted records are not periodically evicted?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

We are using ehcache 2.10.1 and have the configuration below (reported via MBeans):

[image: MBean output]

We actually setting up storage size by:

> cacheManagerConfig.setMaxBytesLocalDisk(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
> cacheManagerConfig.setMaxBytesLocalHeap(1024 * 1024 * 1024);

We are realized that not all elements are evicted from the cache (by a diskExpiryThread or manual calling cache.evictExpiredElements()), but we heavily rely on the cache eviction listener to do some cleanup tasks. The eviction happens on "get", though.

Looking further in the logs we saw

> DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment - fault removed -208 from heap
>
> DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment - fault added 293 on disk

In Segment.java in evict() I saw a piece of code:

```
 if (e != null && !e.faulted.get()) {
     evictedElement = decode(e.element);
 }
```

Since an element is faulted `evictedElement` remains null and eviction does not happen.

Looking at the source code for eviction I saw TODOs that tell that the code should be rewritten or cleaned up.

Now I'm curious whether it's some sort of bug, or we set up our cache incorrectly?

Thanks

**UPD**: From the user perspective I'm curious why methods of `CacheEventListenerAdapter` are not called when `cache.evictExpiredElements()` is called

Comment: Can you state what you expect from a user's perspective? Cause you are mixing external and internal concepts in your question which makes hard to give the answer at the proper level.

Comment: Sorry for that. Elaborated the question.